# Can Hive Work on any storage system or does it need HDFS itself?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hive is always coupled with HDFS. My question is, can Hive run on any other location apart from HDFS? Just like spark, does it support any data storage?

Answer (score 1):

Hive was built for hadoop, and therefore for HDFS. Here is what the [official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial) says about it

> **What Is Hive**
>
> Hive is a data warehousing infrastructure based on Apache Hadoop. Hadoop provides massive scale out and fault tolerance capabilities for data storage and processing on commodity hardware.

Yet, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hive), Hive can work on "compatible" file systems:

> Apache Hive supports analysis of large datasets stored in Hadoop's HDFS and compatible file systems such as Amazon S3 filesystem and Alluxio.

AFAIK, there is no documentation about this in Hive's official documentation but you can find plenty on AWS and Alluxio's websites.

Comment: Hive just uses whatever `fs.defaultFS` is set to, as the HDFS filesystem path, and that's all that needs documentation with regards to Hive